# Flexible DIV height on different page sizes

Tags: html, css

Any idea how to make the middle sections in this code below ([jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JDh7k/)) adjust to the height of the actual container without specifying fixed values or Javascript? In this fiddle I tried setting absolute and relative for the container but the page always shows vertical scrollbar as the height of the container exceeds the height of the actual page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; height:100%;}
        #mainContainer { position: absolute; right: 4%; left: 4%; height: 100%; }
        #headerContainer { width: 100%; position: relative; background: #323232; color: white; height: 30px; }
        #middleContainer { height: 100%; }
        #leftSection { position: absolute; float: left; width: 175px; background: #71ABD1; height: 100%; overflow: auto; color: black; }
        #middleSection { position: absolute; height: 100%; background-color: yellow; left: 175px; right: 175px; color: black; }
        #rightSection { float: right; height: 100%; width: 175px; border-left: 1px dotted black; background: red; color: black; }
        #footerContainer { position: relative; width: 100%; height: 30px; background: #323232; color: white; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="headerContainer">
            headerContainer
        </div>
        <div id="middleContainer">
            <div id="leftSection">
                <div style="margin-top: 30px;">leftSection</div>
            </div>
            <div id="middleSection">
                <div style="margin-top: 30px;">middleSection</div>
            </div>
            <div id="rightSection">
                <div style="margin-top: 30px;">rightSection</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footerContainer">
            footerContainer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

​

Comment: Are you trying to get the middle div to be as tall as the browser window or is this a simple faux columns issue?

Comment: both, I need the middle div to stretch to the height of the window (which would cause the contained left, middle and right columns to stretch too to the height) while keeping the header and footer divs in their place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/XTQuT/2/

Absolute positioning takes `#middleContainer` and `#footerContainer` out of the normal flow. `#middleContainer` is forced to take up the size of the whole page, but is given a margin to allow room for the header and footer. `#footerContainer` is fixed to the bottom of the page with `bottom: 0`. The left and right columns can then just use `height: 100%` to take up the right space, but the middle column still needs absolute positioning to force it to only use the remaining space.

Answer (score 1):

................................

Hi maya i suggest u can u used table properites in your code if yes than check to this ***[demo](http://tinkerbin.com/ZJlIowm7)***

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="conternt">
  <div class="left">Left sdaf dsaklf jdslkaf jdlskfj dlskafj dslkf jdslkf jsdlakfj sdlakfj sdlkf jlsdkfj sladkfj sdalkfj sadlkf </div>
  <div class="center">Center flexible</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>

</div>
```

**Css**

```
.header{
background:green;
  color:#fff;
  padding:20px;
}

.conternt{
background:yellow;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
.left, .right, .center{
display:table-cell;
  color:#fff;
}
.left, .right{
width:100px;
}
.left{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
.center{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
}
.right{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9)
}



.footer{
background:red;
  color:#fff;
  padding:20px;

}
```

***[live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/ZJlIowm7)***

Comment: This does not work, height of the middle div is not fully stretched to the height of page, the footer is not on the bottom end of the browser either.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, @grc answer does the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the height of both `#footerContainer` and `#headerContainer` as percentage instead of pixels, as you do the same for others div. In this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/Xywk6/) I gave 10% to header and footer, and 80% to all intermediante divs.